# How to extract isosurfaces in Paraview using contour filter from gridded files?

Tags: contour, paraview

I have a smooth scalar field [gridded file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huOC0.png) and i want to apply the contour filter to extract the 0 iso surface, as described by [this guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqBRW.png) i am reading, the get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvK9V.png). The software said i can only apply the contour filter on points files (why the guide said that they applied the contour on a gridded file?). I tried to transform blocks to points and then apply the filter, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just use contour with a value of 0 should work.

Comment: The problem is, the contour filter is not available to gridded variables and when i transform it from grid to points i can apply the filter, but it not generates a surface, the output is empty.

Comment: Please share a dataset that reproduce the issue.